# Request a graphql query with axios

Tags: javascript, api, axios, graphql, graphql-java

I'm trying to make a request with a graphql query using axios but failed.
this is my query

```
query {
  workspace(workspaceName: "stackoverflow") {
    name
    company {
      name
    } 
  }
}
```

and my code block

```
  axios({
        url: "https://testurl.com/graphql",
        method: 'post', 
        query: ` query($workspaceName: String!)
           {
              workspace(workspaceName: $workspaceName) {
                 name
                 company {
                   name
                 } 
               }
           }
           `,
        variables: {
           workspaceName: CookieHelper.workspaceName,
        },
        forceResolve: resolve,
     })
        .then(res => {
           resolve(res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
           reject(err);
        });
```

I set it like this because workspaceName value will work parametrically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Axios does not have a `query` property in the options object. All data you're trying to send to the server should be assigned to the `data` property. Or use the `axios.post` function where the second parameter is the same as `data` on `axios()`.

```
const query = `
query($workspaceName: String!) {
  workspace(workspaceName: $workspaceName) {
    name
    company {
      name
    } 
  }
}`;

const variables = {
  workspaceName: CookieHelper.workspaceName,
};

// Use `data` or..
axios({
  url: "https://testurl.com/graphql",
  data: {
    query,
    variables
  }
}).then(res => {
  resolve(res);
}).catch(err => {
  reject(err);
});

// ..use post where the second parameter is the same as data.
axios.post("https://testurl.com/graphql", {
  query,
  variables
}).then(res => {
  resolve(res);
}).catch(err => {
  reject(err);
});
```

I'm not sure what `forceResolve: resolve` did, so I  omitted it from the example.